# How to examples iteration count in cucumber

Tags: cucumber-java

I have seen CucumberScenarioOutline.java file in info.cukes of cucumber but not able to find in io.cucumber package?

Can somebody help?

This is the old class - https://www.javadoc.io/doc/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.0.12/cucumber/runtime/model/CucumberScenarioOutline.html

But in io.cucumber not able to find

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/info.cukes/cucumber-core/1.0.12/cucumber/runtime/model/CucumberScenarioOutline.html